# Motion tracking/VFX: How to get needed info for iPhone camera?

Tags: lens, focal-length, optics, iphone, specification

Basically, I want to do VFX with my iPhone SE 2nd Generation front-facing camera. The software being used is Blender up-to-date. I'm not sure what to set Blender for in the track camera settings field, given that it has these fields,

[image: Blender camera track settings]

...but that Apple provides this:

```
Front Camera
7MP camera
ƒ/2.2 aperture
Portrait mode with advanced bokeh and Depth Control
Portrait Lighting with six effects (Natural, Studio, Contour, Stage, Stage Mono, High-Key Mono)
1080p HD video recording at 25 fps or 30 fps
Retina Flash
QuickTake video
Wide color capture for photos and Live Photos
Auto HDR for photos
Auto image stabilization
Burst mode
Cinematic video stabilization (1080p and 720p)
```

Does anyone have the needed info for motion tracking on an iPhone SE camera? If not, can I accurately calculate it using Blender or other tools? Can I just measure my camera lens with a ruler and calculate the focal length?